# global variable initialization optimization

Tags: c, optimization, global-variables

Global variables are initialized to "0" by default.

How much difference does it make (if any) when I explicitly assign value "0" to it.

Is any one of them faster/better/more optimized?

I tried with a small sample .c program but I do not see any change in executable size.

**Edit:0** I just want to understand the behavior. Its not a bottleneck for me in any way.

Comment: This is a micro optimization I wouldn't concern myself with. It's unlikely to have any noticable change (if any at all).

Comment: If you do a diff between the two executables, you should see that they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is very implementation specific but typically all uninitialized global and static variables end up in the [.bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment. Explicitly initialized variables are located in some other [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). Both of these will be copied over by the program loader before the execution of `main()`. So, there shouldn't be any performance difference between explicitly initializing to zero, and leaving the variable uninitialized.

IMO it is good practice to explicitly initialize globals and statics to zero, as it makes it clear that a zero initial value is expected.

Comment: how can I inspect .bss and data segments? to see whats in there?

Comment: @hari Tell your linker to generate a map file, that will list the various sections

Answer (score 2):

When you say optimized, I am assuming you mean faster in execution. If so, then there won't be any difference. And the compiler might even remove the initialization of the global variable (not sure on the compiler internals). And if you mean the space utilization of the program - there won't be a difference in that either.

Bigger question though is - is there a specific reason you are trying to look to optimize via the initialization of global variables. Can you please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Static objects without an explicit initializer are initialized to zero at startup. Whether you explicitly initialize the object to `0`  or not will probably make no difference in term of performance as the compiler usually initialize all the zero objects in one go before `main`.

```
// File scope
// Same code is likely to be generated for the two objects initialization

int bla1;
int bla2 = 0;
```

On the other hand, if you assign `0` instead of initializing, it could make a difference because the compiler could not infer what was the previous value of the object.

```
void init(void)
{
    bla1 = 0;
    bla2 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a difference, but, even if there is, I have much more doubts about the fact that your program is so optimized that the bottleneck is that.

I'd rather suggest not to care at all about all this kind of issues and write the code as you like, maybe giving way to readability rather than speed, leaving optimization only as a final problem.

*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*

Answer (score 1):

There is none. The optimizer sees that as a no-op.

Explicit initialization is more verbose and clearer to the untrained eye. If you have juniors in your team, I'd explicitly initialize these variables.